# Virtualbox - how to move virtual machine to another PC

Tags: ubuntu, move, virtualbox

Can't move virtual machine to another PC, have copied turnkey-core-2009.10-2-hardy-x86.vmdk to folder .VirtualBox -> HardDisks.

Created new machine, pointed to copied file.

Started created machine and it drops this error after a while(5 mins)

http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/8650/box0.jpg

As i understand, there is some difference in uniq ids, but how to handle it?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Consider asking this question at superuser.com

Comment: offtopic for stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

Go to File->Export Appliance and export the virtual machine, that will create .ovf and .vmdk files you can then import on another machine.

Comment: I have tried. The same effect.

Comment: You imported the .ovf and let VirtualBox move the .vmdk to your .VirtualBox/HardDisks directory?  If so I'm afraid I don't have any other advice, I've moved 4 virtual machines around by exporting and importing them.

Comment: http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/4971/box2r.jpg after doing it via import ovf

Comment: hardware is different on new PC btw

Comment: Maybe it's because of virtualbox versions difference?

Comment: Have entered vm setting and checked some setting and it worked. lol :)

Comment: That error looks familiar, maybe the VM stuff in the bios on the new machine needs to be turned on.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem yesterday (but not the same).

It is not a vBox problem, it is that when you created new machine with VBox, and copied the disk using VBox you have changed the UUID of the disk.

And in you system (whatever it is), you have your old UUID in `/etc/fstab`. You have to boot this new machine from a rescue CD (maybe ubuntu, or dsl. Anything that supports the filesysytem you have on that vritual disk). Then check UUID of your disk using `blkid` command as root. And put this new UUID in fstab, in an entry that specified the boot disk. Maybe you are also using UUID in some other place, that you have to change too.

Another solution is: try to COPY all the virtual disks for this VM and the virtualmachine definition files in your host system, using any copy mechanism you have, but not the VirtualBox Clone or export. And open this machine on new PC (but it will only work on another PC, not on the same). If that does not work, then I do not know.

Additional question: did you try cloning the VM to the same PC. Clone the disk using VirtualBox clone, then create new machine, and update the /etc/fstab?

Hint: in VirtualMachines you can switch from `UUID` entries in fstab to old `/dev/sda` entries.

Another idea: If you are using LargeVolumeManager then you have setup that too. And I do not know how to do it, because I am not using LVM.